# How to remove line with specific string from file

Tags: linux, grep

Note the text file like this:

```
/home/user1/dir1
/home/user1/dir2
/home/user1/
/home/user1/dir1/dir11
```

Goal is to remove line that has just "/home/user1/", nothing besides that, so end result should be:

```
/home/user1/dir1
/home/user1/dir2
/home/user1/dir1/dir11
```

Tried with code below, but it removed all lines that contains /home/user1/ in it. Any idea how this should be done?

```
grep -v "/home/user1/" /home/user1/input.txt > tmpfile && mv tmpfile /home/user1/output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors to mark the beginning and end of the line: `^` for the beginning and `$` for the end. So it would go like this:

```bsh
$ grep -v '^/home/user1/$' file
/home/user1/dir1
/home/user1/dir2
/home/user1/dir1/dir11
```

Alternatively you can use the `-x` option:

```
-x, --line-regexp         match only whole lines
```

Then

```bsh
$ grep -vx '/home/user1/' file
/home/user1/dir1
/home/user1/dir2
/home/user1/dir1/dir11
```

Your `grep` command is doing what it's supposed to, find all the lines that *contain* `/home/user1/`, not the exact match.

Answer (score 0):

If `sed` is an option

```
$ sed -n '\|\(/\([^/]*/\)\{2\}\)\<|p' input_file
/home/user1/dir1
/home/user1/dir2
/home/user1/dir1/dir11
```

Comment: What is the idea behind the outer `\(\)`? And I think that ERE improve readability: `sed -nE '\|/([^/]*/){2}\<|p'`

Answer (score 0):

If that is the exact contents of the file, then here is an easy solution with GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/^\/home\/user1\/$/d' file
```

`^` marks the beginning of the line and `$` marks the end of the line so it will only match that exact string. `\` is used to escape the instances of `/` in the string.

This can be used if the line with the string contains trailing white space:

```
sed '/^\/home\/user1\/[[:space:]]*$/d' file
```

Output:

```
/home/user1/dir1
/home/user1/dir2
/home/user1/dir1/dir11
```

Once you are sure that it does what you want, add `-i` to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i '/^\/home\/user1\/$/d' file

sed -i '/^\/home\/user1\/[[:space:]]*$/d' file
```

Comment: Please note that you can use a different character than `/` for regexp addressing by preceeding it with a backslash, for readabilities sake: `sed '\_^/home/user1/$_d'`. And option `-i` without extension for the backup file is unknown to most `sed` implementation.

Comment: @Philippos I know. I normally use a different delimeter when replacing but when deleting, I just use `/` and escape it out of habit.  Regarding `-I`, that's why I specifically stated `GNU sed`. I am aware that it isn't the same as other instances of `sed` such as what's in MacOS, FreeBSD, or Solaris.